# Deploy not working on Google App Angine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am not able to deploy any project to Google App Engine and this is the error I get

```
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1250, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1045, in Begin
    version=self.version, payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 356, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 391, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 271, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 214, in _GetAuthToken
    response = self.opener.open(req)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 381, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 399, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 1115, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 1082, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: < urlopen error (8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol') >
```

Comment: Your traceback is poorly formatted (try using the code formatting option) and, I think, incomplete; the colon at the end of URLError usually means something will follow.

Comment: It was working till a hour ago. It looks like timeout issue, not sure. How do I resolve it?

Comment: I've made the error message visible by reformatting the error trace. Hope somebody knows what to do about it.

Comment: thx Carl, +1 for your change. How do you indent lengthy text by 4 spaces in SO editor. When I press TAB the text itself disappeared.

Comment: Just press the code button in the toolbar when having your code selected, or indent by using (surprise, surprise) the spacebar 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like fiddler was interfering with upload, I did not know how to disable it so stopped it and then upload happened instantly. I got the clue from this [blogpost](http://andrewgrossmanatwork.blogspot.com/2009/02/sslerror-8-eof-occurred-in-violation-of.html).

Specially the part

> proxies can result in this problem, which is likely caused by the HTTP header send being terminated prematurely.